# Macbook Air will only Boot in Safe Boot

Tags: macbook-pro

So after multiple startup problems with my Macbook Air i managed to get it to boot once upgraded the OS to Catalina hoping that it would solve previous startup problems.

Also ran First Aid from Disk Utilities but it still will not boot normally.

I can access Safe Boot but cannot access Recovery or MacOS Utilities ..

I have checked the RAM in System and they both have OK Status so i believe this to be some other hardware or driver issue.

My question is if i cannot access MacOS Utilities or Recovery mode how can i format and reinstall OS to rule out software issues ?

Comment: What happens, precisely, when you try to boot normally? If you can boot in 'Safe' mode that would tend to rule out a physical problem with the hardware (though not necessarily problems with the disk itself). Have you tried the various diagnostics listed here: https://www.howtogeek.com/189104/troubleshoot-your-mac-with-these-hidden-startup-options/ ?

Comment: Yeh basically the only thing i can do on that list is enter SAFE BOOT .. anything else just hangs on the apple logo and progress bar or black screen with infinite chime ... but not standard 3 0r 9 chimes pointing at RAM .. i mean it just doesn't stop until i hard reboot .. but it goes into Safe Boot perfectly and runs uninterrupted ..

Comment: Well, that's odd. Hmph. Ok, I've never done this myself, but according to https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reinstall-macos-mchlp1599/mac you can reinstall MacOS directly from the internet. That should give you the option to reformat as well. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks but i cannot access recovery mode or any other mode besides Safe Boot

Comment: So update ... Command + V = Verbose mode, managed to now get access by entering Verbose Mode but not releasing Command + V .. I know this makes no sense at all .. but this is the only way to get in other than Safe Boot  .. So whilst i am in now in regular boot mode what should i do ? Are there any tools that i can use to repair or diagnose ? They have to be available within normal OS running mode as i still can't access anything else on Boot ..

Comment: Installing from the internet does not require you to enter *any* mode. Restart your machine, and hold down opt-comd-R immediately. That should bypass the normal startup routine and go directly to install mode.

Answer (score 1):

I start in safe mode occasionally when my machine is acting up. I do so because certain startup items, especially 3rd party ones, can cause problems. I'd turn off all startup items and see if that helps with your problem.

Comment: This was a great suggestion, but unfortunately i have no items listed in startup items.